# Best practice for ignoring empty values in .each() loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of code:

```
self.list.push(values);
for (var i = 1; i < $(elemthree, this).text().match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, '$1'); i++) {
    self.list.push(values); 
}
```

It iterates through a bunch of data on a site and outputs an array value for certain elements, multiple times if necessary. This is ran across multiple sites (10+).

However, one site in particular returns 2500+ empty rows of data after 30 rows that I need, resulting in a TON of processing time once the array is completed and gets parsed by an external program. I fixed it by wrapping this bit of code in the following:

```
if (values != '') {
    self.list.push(values);
    for (var i = 1; i < $(elemthree, this).text().match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, '$1'); i++) {
        self.list.push(values); 
    }
}
```

This works as intended, and doesn't add the empty rows to the list - and also seems to be future proof for any sites whose data I might want to parse in the future. But it feels hacky to me. Did I go about this the right way? Was there a better method to doing this?

(Before anyone mentions the fact that I have a loop starting at i = 1 as opposed to i = 0 and removing the first self.list.push - that is intentional due to some parsed sites not mentioning quantity and instead just listing a value I need once.)

Comment: The for loop doesn't make sense to me. So you are pushing the same value to array multiple times?

Comment: Yes. I'm making a list of items that may appear multiple times in the form of (Array Value) x 2. BUT, if it appears once, then it's just (Array Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// check it is emtpy

```
if (!values) {
  self.list.push(values);
  for (var i = 1; i < $(elemthree, this).text().match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, '$1'); i++) {
    self.list.push(values); 
  }
}
```

// check it is empty or whitespace

```
if (!values.trim()) {
  self.list.push(values);
  for (var i = 1; i < $(elemthree, this).text().match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/g, '$1'); i++) {
    self.list.push(values); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's Okay.  Except there are many other undesirable values where `!= ''` will equate to TRUE.

Think in terms of what you want rather than do not want.

You want a string with a length greater than zero.  Use that.

```
if (values.length > 0)
```